# Rails - Handling Nil value in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I am using the `Twitter gem` to retrieve specific tweets and save them to my database. I'd like to handle `nil` value and use `unless item.blank?` for this purpose. Here is my code:

```
def self.get_tweets user
 all_tweets = CLIENT.user_timeline(user, count: "20", exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
 good_tweets = all_tweets.select{ |t| t.retweet_count + t.favorite_count > 0}
 good_tweets.each do |tweet|
  Twit.find_or_create_by(link: "#{tweet.uri}") do |twit|
    twit.content = tweet.text unless tweet.text.blank?
    twit.like = tweet.favorite_count
    twit.retweet = tweet.retweet_count
    twit.first_date = tweet.created_at
    twit.engagement = twit.like + twit.retweet
    twit.image_url = tweet.media[0].media_url unless tweet.media[0].media_url.blank?
    twit.content_url = tweet.urls[0].expanded_url.to_s.split("?")[0] unless tweet.urls[0].blank?
  end
 end
end
```

However, I understand it is not the good way to proceed as my code first crashes ad when I am refreshing my page I got my localhost url `http://localhost:3000/twits` as value which is not what I want.

How can I elegantly handle this error? I have been learning Ruby/Rails on my own for one month so it's not so clear. Thank you.

Comment: You ask "How can I elegantly handle this error? " but you neglect to iinclude the text of the error.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, the error is the following "undefined method `media_url' for nil:NilClass". It happens because some tweets I need to save don't have all the attribute, some my script fails... I need to save tweets properly even if they don't have an image_url, text or link inside for instance. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because you're trying to get the media_url for a tweet with no media:

```
twit.image_url = tweet.media[0].media_url unless tweet.media[0].media_url.blank?
```

so you could use

```
twit.image_url = tweet.media[0].media_url unless tweet.media[0].blank? || tweet.media[0].media_url.blank?
```

I would prefer the opposite logic

```
twit.image_url = tweet.media[0].media_url if tweet.media[0].present?
```

Or even shorter

```
twit.image_url = tweet.media[0].try(:media_url)
```